# Does Magento provide utility functions to use in Views?

Tags: function, magento, view

I'm developing some Views for a Magento module, and I was wondering if there are shortcut functions that can be used to generate HTML tags instead of the usual printf/sprintf. For example, some frameworks offer functions such as `Anchor()`, which, given a text, transforms it into a full  tag, or `TextBox()`, which prints a full  tag.

Does Magento have anything similar, or do I have to stick to the "*printf*" method? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Magento's Blocks (which is what I assume you're asking about re: Views) don't offer HTML generation methods.  You'll need to manually generate HTML code in PHP **or** use template blocks, which allow you to write your own html code in `phtml` template files, and then intersperse that code with calls to

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?=$link;?>"><?= $label; ?></a>
```

depending on how you role

Comment: Thanks Alan. At least now I'm sure it's not me that can't find the methods, they really are not there. I lost a bit of confidence in my search skills when I discovered the existence of the "__()" function. I may be picky, but "double underscore" is not really intuitive as a function name...

Comment: @Diego The __ function is taking cues from gettext, which is a 17 year old software package for translations that uses a similar (single underscore) convention. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know there must have been a reason behind choosing such convention, but "double underscore" is not an intuitive name (and it's also hard to read, at least for me). Please note that this is not an attack towards Magento as a whole, if I had used GetText (which I didn't), I'd have said the same about it. Anyway, now that I know it, it will be easier to handle. Funnily enough, the underscore naming is one of the "best practices" listed in "How to write unmaintainable code" (http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainnaming.html). (it's just for a laugh, nothing personal). :)